# Need help With getter in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Hi I am working on one requirement in which i need to display one filed on the UI as per availability in the javascript of the LWC.

selctedFundName and selectedStrategy

initially both are assigned ''-->>>blank value.

req :-
if both the values are present then selctedFundName should be displayed on the UI.
and if selctedFundName is undefined and selectedStrategy then selectedStrategy  should be displayed on the UI --

tried below approach :

```
Javascript:
get displayFundName() {
        if (this.selctedFundName != '' && this.selectedStrategy != '') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    get displayFundStrategy() {
        if (this.selectedStrategy != '' && this.selctedFundName == 'undefined') {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

HTML :

```
<lightning-layout-item class='slds-var-m-top_xx-large slds-var-m-bottom_small'>
                    <template if:true={displayFundName}>
                        <div
                            class='slds-text-heading_small slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label clear-value slds-m-left_medium slds-custom-marging-bottom'>
                            Selected Product - {selctedFundName}
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    <template if:true={displayFundStrategy}>
                        <div
                            class='slds-text-heading_small slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label clear-value slds-m-left_medium slds-custom-marging-bottom'>
                            Selected Strategy - {selectedStrategy}
                        </div>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout-item>
```

Issue :--- not getting populated or displaying on the uI as per requirement.

Comment: Hello Tanya, could you please clarify what is being displayed? (one of the templates two or none)?

Comment: only selected Product is displayed

Comment: It means that both `selctedFundName` and `selectedStrategy` are not empty strings. Have you checked the values of these two variables? btw: on `displayFundStrategy` you are comparing `selctedFundName` against a string containing `undefined` instead of undefined value (e.g. this.selctedFundName == undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `'undefined'` is different than `undefined`. The former is a string with the word `undefined` in it, the latter is a type of null value that means "an undefined value."

Note that in JavaScript, both of these values are considered "[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)", so you can use behavior to write the logic simply as:

```
get displayFundStrategy() {
    return !!this.selectedStrategy && !!this.selctedFundName;
}
```